# Unit testing with jasmine and restangular - cannot instantiate module restangular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, restangular

I'm trying to unit test a service that uses restangular. I have tried a couple ways to include restangular in the unit the first is doing it in a beforeEach like so:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module("restangular"));
```

The above is seen in the restangular unit testing.

I've also tried.

```
beforeEach(angular.module("restangular"));
```

And then lastly i've tried the following which is seen in this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hNmxWR?p=info

```
it('should inject restangular', inject(function(Restangular) {
    expect(Restangular).toBeDefined();  
        //... do stuff with 
}));
```

each time I run a unit test I get the following error:

```
 Failed to instantiate module restangular due to:
 Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'restangular' is not available! You either      misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=restangular
```

Any ideas? This is what my service looks like for an example:

```
angular
.module('schoolsService' ['restangular'])
.factory('schoolsService', function(Restangular) {
var schools = Restangular.all('/report/school');
return {
        getSchools: function(schoolType) {
            return schools.get(schoolType);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it:

```
describe("schoolsService test", function () {

    beforeEach(module("schoolsService"));
    beforeEach(module("restangular"));

    var schoolsService, Restangular;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_schoolsService_, _Restangular_){
        schoolsService = _schoolsService_;
        Restangular = _Restangular_;
    });

    it("performs a test", function(){
        // expect something
    });

});
```

Also, remember to include these modules in the config files!